# Is ther a design pattern for working with an unknown object store?

Tags: design-patterns

I'm writing a REST framework, and I'd like to implement oauth 2.0. The problem is that I don't want to have any restrictions on the database this is run against.

So The way I'm thinking about implementing this, is by letting the developer implement their own DataStore class, which implements methods for me to interact with. I'm working in Python, so there's no way to define an interface like you do in java, but I'm creating a base class that just raises NotImplemented for any method call, which developers should subclass.

For my case, the Datastore object would have methods like this:

```
class DataStore(object):
    def store_client(client_id, client_secret, client_urls):
        ...

    def get_client(client_id, client_secret)
        ...

    def store_token(client_id, token):
        ...

....
```

And the developer would implement these methods using their data storage method of choice, although I would provide some implementations for common databases.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: There are no "better" ways, there are alternative ways but that is it. Each will have their own trade-offs.

Comment: I'd be interested to learn more about these alternatives in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will state that this is an alternative which may or may not be "better" or more suitable to your needs. What you're showing in your example is a traditional DAO or Datastore type pattern. Wherein the object model exposes methods which do all the CRUD actions: read, update, create and delete. The downside of this is that as more logic is needed either in the query or in querying the data itself, a simple class of 3-4 exposed methods can grow into 20+ methods.

This is where you start thinking about each individual action being a different, separate identity. Hence, you might have an "Accessor" object with simple interface like:

```
 class GetClient(object):
   def get(self, client_id):
     pass
```

but have several different variations on the theme like:

```
 class AuthenticatedGetClient(GetClient):
   def __init__(self, authorization_service, current_user):
     #stuff
   def get(self, client_id):
     if self.auth_svc.permit(self.current_user, client_id):
       #actual client get, perhaps you need to screen out additional details, etc.
```

This follows more of a [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) approach, where the Model you represent to the View may actually be different or an amalgamation of several DB Models together. Example: User model may store user_name while Address stores address and there doesn't really exist a "Profile" Model in the DB.

The benefit here is that you can mix in more complicated access patterns while abstracting away the datastore and reducing the quantity of different API calls which are presented to any other developers. The downside is that you need to create a different object representation for each of the CRUD operations.